# Java Code: Creating a Draw app

Tags: java, button, jframe, jpanel, draw

i'm trying to create a small drawing tool in java. I want the color the user is drawing with to change when they select a button. I tried to set up my buttons to do such. But when I run the app and select a button the color does not change. How can I fix this?

myJPanel.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class myJPanel extends JPanel implements MouseMotionListener, ActionListener
{
    JButton red, blue, yellow, eraser;
    JPanel p1;
    Graphics gg;
    public myJPanel()
    {
        setBackground(Color.white);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
        red = new JButton("Red");
        blue = new JButton("Blue");
                yellow = new JButton("Yellow");
        eraser = new JButton("Eraser");
        p1.add(red);
        p1.add(blue);
                p1.add(yellow);
        p1.add(eraser);
        add(p1,"South");

                addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent evt)
    {

    }


    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent evt)
    {
        Point pt = evt.getPoint();
        int x = pt.x;
        int y = pt.y;
        Graphics gg = getGraphics();
        gg.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        gg.fillRect(x, y, 5, 5);
     }

    @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {

            Object obj = event.getSource();
    String choice = event.getActionCommand();

            if (obj == red) {
        gg.setColor(Color.red);
    }

    if (obj == blue) {
        gg.setColor(Color.blue);
        }


    if (obj == yellow) {
        gg.setColor(Color.yellow);
    }
    if (obj == eraser) {
        gg.setColor(Color.white);
    }
            }


}
```

Comment: Never use `getGraphics()` on a component to get your Graphics. Draw within the JPanel's paintComponent method as the tutorials will show you.

Answer (score 0):

You use a graphics that is not used to paint.

Whatever, don't draw like this, override `paintComponent` method to make it draw what you like, and call `repaint`when you need the drawing to be made:

```
public class myJPanel extends JPanel implements MouseMotionListener, ActionListener
{
    JButton red, blue, yellow, eraser;
    JPanel p1;
    Color currentColor;
    int x, y;
    public myJPanel() {
        setBackground(Color.white);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
        yellow = new JButton("Yellow");
        eraser = new JButton("Eraser");
        p1.add(yellow);
        p1.add(eraser);
        add(p1,"South");
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { // draw something on request
        g.setColor(currentColor);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 5, 5);
    }
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent evt)
    {
        Point pt = evt.getPoint();
        x = pt.x;
        y = pt.y;
        repaint(); // a new point to draw, please call me back...
     }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
      Object obj = event.getSource();
      String choice = event.getActionCommand();

      if (obj == yellow) {
        currentColor = Color.yellow);
      }
      if (obj == eraser) {
        currentColor = Color.white);
      }
  }
}
```